# How do I texture a tree in Blender?

Tags: texturing

I'm having issues applying a texture to a tree in Blender.

I have tried many different ways to add a bark texture to a tree using the sappling add on, here is the list of things i have tried:
 - I have used the UV unwrap in the modifier menu.
 - I have made it into a mesh by going Alt+c>convert to mesh>unwrap                   and then unwrap it in the image editor.
 - I have mde into a mesh and unwraped it as a cube projection.

What can i do to add the texture without it looking stretched or wierd (by wierd i mean a wierd pattern).

I'm using cycles render, version 2.75.

Comment: Welcome! Could you add a picture of the weird pattern? And a picture of your UV map too? Probably your unwrapping is not correct, but some pictures to talnk about would be useful to give you more precise advices.

Comment: Probably to unwrap such shape like a tree you shouldn't use Cube Projection, rather than mark seams needed on the trunk and use `U` > `Unwrap`.